# Mercurial diff including first changeset

Tags: mercurial, diff, changeset

I have recently encountered the need to generate a Mercurial diff of all changes up to a particular changeset which includes the first changeset of the repo. I realize this kind of stretches the definition of a diff, but this is for uploading a new project to a code review tool.

Let's assume the following changesets:

> p83jdps99shjhwop8 - second feature 12:00 PM
>
> hs7783909dnns9097 - first feature - 11:00 AM
>
> a299sdnnas78s9923 - original app setup - 10:00 AM

If I need a "diff" of all changes that have been committed, the only way that I can seem to achieve this is with the following diff command...

```
diff -r 00:p83jdps99shjhwop8
```

In this case the first changeset in the argument param (here - `00`) takes the regexp form of `0[0]+`

This seems to be exactly what we need based on a few tests, but I have had trouble tracking down documentation on this scenario (maybe I just can't devise the right Google query). As a result, I am unsure if this will work universally, or if it happens to be specific to my setup or the repos I have tested by chance.

**Is there a suggested way to achieve what I am trying to accomplish? If not, is what I described above documented anywhere?**

Comment: I believe `hg diff -r null:tip` is what you're after? (If everything you want is an ancestor of `tip`, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears this actually is documented, but you need to do some digging...

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ChangeSetID
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Nodeid

So the special nodeid you're referring to is the 'nullid'.

2 digits may not be adequate to identify the nullid as such (as it may be ambiguous if other hashes start with 2 zeros), so you may be better off specifying 4 0's or more.

Eg: `hg diff -r 00:<hash of initial add changeset>` has resulted in the `abort: 00changelog.i@00: ambiguous identifier!` error.

Comment: It would prob be best just to use the long form of the nullid.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused about what you need. The diff between an empty repository and the revision `tip` is just the content of every file at `tip`-- in other words, it's the state of your project at `tip`. In diff format, that'll consist exclusively of `+` lines.

Anyway, if you want a way to refer to the initial state of the repository, the documented notation for it is `null` (see `hg help revisions`). So, to get a diff between the initial (empty) state and the state of your repository at `tip`, you'd just say

```
hg diff -r null -r tip
```

But `hg diff` gives you a diff between two points in your revision graph. So this will only give you the ancestors of `tip`: If there are branches (named or unnamed) that have not been merged to an ancestor of `tip`, you will not see them.

```
  3--6
 / 
0--1--2--5--7 (tip)
    \   / 
      4
```

In the above example, the range from `null` to `7` does not include revisions `3` and `6`.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that this worked. When you run this sort of diff, diff outputs the short form of the nullid @mrokitka mentioned. Both work though.

Comment: Well, you did ask for a documented way to refer to the null revision. `hg help` is as canonical as it gets.